# MySQL: COUNTS with more WHERE`s in 1 query

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause

Is it possible to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(username) as username FROM users WHERE username = 'Piet';
SELECT COUNT(email) as email FROM users WHERE email = 'piet@google.nl';
SELECT COUNT(ip_registed) as ip FROM users WHERE ip = '127.0.0.1';
```

In one query (so without subqueries)?

Comment: Since the queries really have no relation, three subqueries (or three separate queries) probably are the fastest way to query. You could add upp the rows that match, but that'd (afaik) not use any indexing but a full table scan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use `SUM()` this should do the trick, using sum with expression will result in a boolean 1 or 0,so when your expression evaluates to true this will give you the count accordingly,also when aggregate functions are used without group they will result in a single row,and assume the whole table as one group

```
SELECT
SUM(username = 'Piet') as username,
SUM(email = 'piet@google.nl') as email,
SUM(ip = '127.0.0.1') as ip
FROM users
```

Comment: A `true` MySQL Solution.

Comment: If someone calls that to dirty, just take `sum(if(username='Piet', 1, 0))`. I like it the "dirty" way (since boolean is naturally 0|1, isn't it?)

Comment: @flaschenpost an if statement and also a case statement can be used but the shortest way i have show in answer the one solution you are calling it dirty i.e (if/case) they are more readable i don't believe they are dirty